# cannot open 'libboost_container-vc143-mt-s-x64-1_84.lib' while building the release version of a windows console CS C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, boost, iot

I am currently utilising the C++ boost libraries `https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/more/getting_started/windows.html` in windows x64 console c++ project.

While I am building the release version of it, it throws this error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_container-vc143-mt-s-x64-1_84.lib'   gpio_app_cpp    C:\Users****.m\source\repos**\LINK    1

I have built the libraries from the source:
The below commands are given from the root folder(i.e.boost_1_84_0)
`bootstrap  ./b2`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDHn1.png)

Even adding them to both C/C++ and Linker of the configuration properties. Still, I am unable to build the release version of the app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9LFJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjBBQ.png)

Kindly let me where I am missing.

Comment: Seems like you only built the debug version of the boost libraries. IIRC `b2 release` builds the release version. It's all documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). Try looking in your libs folder and see what you have actually built. The boost libraries follow regular naming conventions, so it's easy to work out if you have release versions, debug versions, static versions, dynamic versions, which platform, etc. etc.

Comment: Which libraries are in your `stage\lib` directory? Is `libboost_container-vc143-mt-s-x64-1_84.lib` there?